# MVC Remote Validation in partial view in master layout - "No url for remote validation could be found error" when hit with spiders

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I have just completed a site LostPetListings.com that has partial views within the master layout. I have a partial view "Create Account" that has remote validation on the Email property that works fine. I even can see the data-val-remote-url="/en-us/Validation/EmailExists" in the html, it tests fine when examining the request using Firebug. Problem: I'm getting a ton of errors for "No url for remote validation could be found." when Googlebot hits the site? I can't understand why? **An email that exists in db is t@t.com to test it..**

My Model:

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(SharedStrings), ErrorMessageResourceName = "EmailRequired")]
[MyRemote("EmailExists", "Validation", "", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(SharedStrings), ErrorMessageResourceName = "EmailAlreadyExists")]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

My Attribute:

```
 public class MyRemoteAttribute : RemoteAttribute
    {
        public MyRemoteAttribute(string action, string controller, string area)
            : base(action, controller, area)
        {
            this.RouteData["area"] = area;
        }
    }
```

Validation Controller decorated with:

```
 [OutputCache(Location = OutputCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
```

Validation Controller Action:

```
 [HttpGet]
         public JsonResult EmailExists(string Email)
        {
            string culture = RouteData.Values["culture"]==null?"en-us":RouteData.Values["culture"].ToString().Replace("_", "-").ToLower();

            if (Email != "" && SecurityHelper.ReferrerIsValid) 
            {
                EndUser_Translated eut = endUserTranslatedRepository.Get(d => d.EndUser.Email == Email.Trim() && d.Culture == culture);

                if(eut==null)
                    return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                else
                    return Json(SharedStrings.EmailAlreadyExists, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

            }
            else
                return Json(SharedStrings.EmailAlreadyExists, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

         }
```

How Partial is loaded in Master layout:

```
@Html.Partial("_CreateAccount", new RegisterModel())
```

Everything works great so can't understand why I'm getting this error 'many' from bots [looked up IP I'm catching with error in error log... Googlebot especially]? Might it have something to do with partials cached in master layout or something? Any ideas/guesses welcome even if not correct in the end as it may bring to mind something..

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException: No url for remote validation could be found.
at System.Web.Mvc.RemoteAttribute.GetUrl(ControllerContext controllerContext)
at System.Web.Mvc.RemoteAttribute.d__0.MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Enumerable.d__71`1.MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Enumerable.d__14`2.MoveNext()
at System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper.GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes(String name, ModelMetadata metadata)
at System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.InputHelper(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, InputType inputType, ModelMetadata metadata, String name, Object value, Boolean useViewData, Boolean isChecked, ...

Comment: I think I found what was happening!!! I had an exception that was erasing the RouteValues.Values["Culture"] in my routes...the cached page was showing the correct culture in the url..but on any navigation my culture was gone....so the problem was upstream from this original suspect issue. I think I'm good now as the error emails have stopped. I'll know within the hour for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was it...I had an exception that was erasing the RouteValues.Values["Culture"] in my routes...the cached page was showing the correct culture in the url..but on any navigation my culture was gone....so the problem was upstream. In short, if a url dependent operation is acting weird check your route table..? It helped me